# Mail Stuck in Outbox of Outlook 2013 sent using Redemption

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption, outlook-2013

Currently i am in a process of migrating applications to new version, i am  facing a problem in the application. Basically its a VBA Access application which will send reports to users. For the mail delivery part it uses Redemption.dll

**Current Versions:**

- Windows XP
- MS Office 2003
- Redemption.dll v 4.5.0.812

**Migrating To**

- Windows 7
- MS Office 2013
- Redemption.dll v 4.5.0.812

**Scenario 1:** In Win 7 machine using the **redemption.dll v 4.5.0.812** when i run the application, the report delivery function runs without errors. But what i noticed is the mails are stuck in Outbox. When i open Outlook 2013 the mails get delivered. So when i keep outlook open and run the function the mails get delivered.

**Scenario 2:** Now in Win 7 machine using the developer version **redemption.dll v 5.14** too the mail get stuck in Outbox.

What could be the reason, is there need to do code changes or is it some setting changes related to Outlook 2013? 
Any kind of help would be very useful.... need it badly :-) 
If there is a need to do code changes, is it possible keeping the redemption.dll version v 4.5 (as per the requirement)

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#1

**When I send a message using Redemption, it simply stays in the Drafts folder**

Message submission is a two step process in Extended MAPI:

1. Calling IMessage::Submit()
2. Flushing the outgoing message queue.

If you are using an Exchange Server, step #2 is not required since Exchange Message Store is tightly bound with the Exchange Transport provider. If you however are using a POP3/SMTP transport and a PST file as a message store, step #2 is required. To flush the message queues, create an instance of Redemption.MAPIUtils object and call its DeliverNow method (similar to Session.DeliverNow in CDO) after calling SafeMailItem.Send:

```
MailItem.Send
Set Utils = CreateObject("Redemption.MAPIUtils")
Utils.DeliverNow
```

There is however one problem if you are using Outlook 2002 or newer with a PST file and POP3/SMTP transport provider or Outlook 2000 installed in the Internet Only Mode: there is no way to flush the queues using Extended MAPI. That part of Outlook is simply broken. Note however that Outlook 2002/2003 (online) with an Exchange Server or Outlook 2000 C/W in any configuration are fine.

If you are using Outlook 2003 or higher with Exchange in a cached mode, it will exhibit the same problem. Uncheck "Use cached mode" in the Exchange Server properties to force online mode - that will ensure that messages are delivered immediately.

As a last resort, you can simulate clicking "Send/Receive" button in Outlook after sending a message:

```
MailItem.Send
Set Btn = Application.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(1, 5488) 
Btn.Execute
```

Note that in Outlook 2003 that button is now a dropdown, the real Send/Receive is a subitem of the button:

```
Set Btn = Application.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(1, 7095)
Btn.Execute
```

Note that the code above assumes that there is an active Explorer; this will not be the case if you start Outlook programmatically (and it was not previously started by a user) and do not display any folders. In this case you can start a sync using the the Namespace.SyncObjects collection.:

```
 set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 NS.Logon
 Set Sync = NS.SyncObjects.Item(1)
 Sync.Start
```

In Outlook 2010 you can also use `Namespace.SendAndReceive` method.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your reply. After going through it, i Unchecked "Use cached mode" in outlook 2013 to force online mode and the mail did get delivered immediately. Now i have another query, as mentioned **"If you are using Outlook 2003 or higher with Exchange in a cached mode"** but in my current version of outlook 2003 the Use Cached mode is Checked and the mails are delivered with no issues. So is turning off Cached mode is the solution or is there any changes i can do and keep the cached mode ON.

Comment: You can use Namespace.SendAndReceive, but keep in mind that it is asynchronous, you need to make sure Outlook stays referenced until Send/Receive completes.

Comment: Thanks once again Dmitry, my bad i was checking the use cached mode in the wrong machine. It doesn't work with Outlook 2003 and higher. Wonderful, there is no need for any code changes

Comment: hi, i migrated the application to windows 7 with outlook 2013 but when i send email through redemption

   Set oRedemptionMail = CreateObject ("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
                oRedemptionMail.Item = oItemMail
                oRedemptionMail.Send

The email remains in the draft folder can y help me ?